# Merge Sort is looping continuously and going into segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, merge, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement merge sort using arrays.My code is jumping into the loop and not stopping.I need to use Ctrll+Z to stop my program.Basically I am reading from a file and passing that array into mergesort function and then I write again into a file.After writing into a file I calculate the programming time and display it.Please check my below code.Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

clock_t start=clock();
void mergesort(int *,int,int);
void merge(int *,int,int,int);
void writesortedrraytofile(int *,int);

static char *opfile=(char *)"output.txt";

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
        FILE *fp;
        char line[80];
        int array[1000000];
        int i=0,counter;
        int choice;


        printf("The command line arguments are:\n");
        printf("%d %s %s %s\n",argc,argv[0],argv[1],argv[2]);

        if(argc==3 && strcmp(argv[0],"./sorting")==0 && strcmp(argv[1],"input1.txt")==0 && strcmp(argv[2],"output.txt")==0)
        {
                printf("The command line arguments are correct.\n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("The command line arguments are wrong.I am exiting.\n");
                exit (0);
        }
fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
while(fgets(line,80,fp) !=NULL)
{
        sscanf(line,"%d",&array[i]);
        i++;
}
counter=i;
fclose(fp);
    mergesort(array,0,counter);
        }
        return 0;
}

void mergesort(int *temp,int begin,int end)
{
        int mid=0;
        if(begin<end)
        {
                mid=(begin+end)/2;
                mergesort(temp,begin,mid);
                mergesort(temp,mid+1,end);
        }
                merge(temp,begin,mid,end);
}

void merge(int *temp,int low,int mid,int high)
{
        int i,k;
        int *tmp = (int *) malloc((high - low +1)* sizeof(int));
        int begin1 = low;
        int end1 = mid;
        int begin2= mid +1;
        int end2 = high;

        for ( k = 0; begin1 <= end1 && begin2 <= end2; k++)
                if (temp[begin1] < temp[begin2])
                        tmp[k] = temp[begin1 ++];
                else
                        tmp[k] = temp[begin2 ++];
        while (begin1 <= end1)
                tmp[k++] = temp[begin1 ++];
        while (begin2 <= end2)
                tmp[k++] = temp[begin2 ++];
        for ( i =0;i < high -low +1; i ++)
                temp[low +i] = tmp[i];
        free(tmp);
        writesortedrraytofile(tmp,high-low+1);
        return;
}


void writesortedrraytofile(int *ssarray,int len)
{
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen(opfile,"w");
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n",ssarray[i]);
        fclose(fp);
        printf("The output file is generated.Please check it inside the directory.\n");
        printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        return;
}
```

Comment: If would help if you told us _which_ loop would not stop. Also, have you tried to step though the code in a debugger?

Comment: The display time is getting printed multiple times.. As in writesortedrraytofile function is looping again and again.. This is creating the problem...

Comment: @Vutukuri `writesortedrraytofile` is called in `merge` once, but `merge` again is called in `mergesort` which calls itself recursively -> every call of mergesort leads to one call of `writesortedrraytofile` -> time printed multiple times

Comment: Does below answer work for you?

Comment: @Halex But I need to write the numbers into a file.... how can I do that without passing an array?

Comment: @Vutukuri You need not write the numbers at every merge step but at the end when the array is sorted. Remove the call to `writesortedrraytofile` from the function `merge` and add it after the call `mergesort(array,0,counter);` in your `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try the code by myself, but using such a big array as a local variable doesn't sound like a very good idea. You also don't do any boundary checks when reading into the file. This may corrupt your stack and lead to unpredictable results.

A better solution might be:

```
#define MAX_COUNT 1000000
int* array = (int*)malloc(MAX_COUNT * sizeof(int));
```

and

```
while((fgets(line,80,fp) !=NULL) && (i < MAX_COUNT))
```

Comment: There's a problem if you do both of those things. When you change `array` to a pointer then `sizeof(array)` returns the pointer size (probably 4 or 8). Better to `#define` or declare a variable to hold the array size and use that in place of the magic number 1000000.

Comment: `new int`? This is tagged C, not C++. Real men use malloc.

Comment: Indeed, I changed my snippets to use malloc and corrected the boundary check.

Answer (score 0):

In mergesort, you have written `int mid=0`. Instead do this:

```
int mid=(begin+end)/2;
```

That fixes segmentation fault. Now call writesortedrraytofile from at the end of main() method instead of from merge(). This will fix recursive output into output.txt.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
  counter=i;
  fclose(fp)
  mergesort(array,0,counter);
  writesortedrraytofile(array,counter); // call writesortedrraytofile from here
}
```

After this you get sorted numbers in output.txt. Still there is one more problem. For input: (3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 10) output is coming: (0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9). Not sure why last number is getting replaced by 0. This problem is certainly because of a bug in merge().

**EDIT-** Found the problem with 0 coming into output. The next fix would be to pass `counter-1` instead of `counter` to mergesort(). After this programs works quite fine.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
  counter=i;
  fclose(fp)
  mergesort(array,0,counter-1); // pass counter-1 instead of counter
  writesortedrraytofile(array,counter); // call writesortedrraytofile from here
}
```

Comment: `mid=(begin+end)/2` should be avoided because it can lead to integer overflow l. Use `mid=begin+(end-begin)/2`

Comment: If concerned array can be so large that (begin + end) causes integer overflow, it is just better to use long type.

Comment: On my system for example `sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)` so that does not solve the overflow problem. Indeed you could work with `long long` *or* just use the safe formula. I prefer the latter.

Comment: No, that still does not make sense. What if variable 'end' itself causes integer overflow. Note that if we declare 'begin' and 'end' as int and if both variables do not counter integer overflow, then variable 'mid' will certainly not counter integer overflow (because 'mid' < 'end'). Hope you get my logic.

Comment: It's the sum of `begin` and `end` that can overflow and after dividing by 2 can be negative. See the following blog post: http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.at/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html Your logic is misleading.

Comment: You are not getting my point. This case means 'end' is already too big. It must be more than MAX_INT/2 for (begin+end) getting overflowed. In that case this approach is an incremental approach. The cleaner way is to use a data type which accommodates your requirement (here you want 'end' more than MAX_INT/2 and then what is guarantee that tomorrow you wont want it to be more than MAX_INT?).

Comment: You give me a data type that you are handling `begin` and `end` with. With your formula `(begin+end)/2` you are limited to arrays that have the maximum size of MAX_YOURTYPE/2. With my approach `begin+(end-begin)/2` you can remove the restriction of half the range of your data type and it is not slower. I can not see any drawbacks at my approach. Mine can handle arrays double the size than yours without having to use a larger data type with probable slower computing

Comment: When range is concerned, your approach works only for double of the range already supported. When I say 'only', it is a temporary solution as if an application now requires support of double of a range, 2 years down the time it may require support of say 4 times of that range. Now the slower computation, I would rather say that it is a choice. IF you now need to support range between MAX_TYPE and MAX_TYPE/2 and later 2 years you have to change the data-type across code just because scale of your application increased, I would choose better data-type NOW with expense of slower computation.